# Issue with VB.NET code accessing Registry

Tags: vb.net, com, registry, dts

I have a program (VB.NET) that when run as a part of a DTS package (using WS Shell) runs fine and is able to access the registry paths. But when I run the same program locally it fails and is it unable to access the Registry.

Below is the stripped out piece of the code that I think is causing the issue.

```
Sub Main()            
        Dim RegObjRegistry_definst As RegObj.Registry
        Try

            RegObjRegistry_definst = New RegObj.Registry
            'The above object has Nothing after defination on a local run

            Console.WriteLine("Success")
            Console.ReadLine()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Following are the references in the project:

[image]

The highlighted dll enables us to access the Registry

The Server is `x86` and the Project build platform is `x86`

The user profiles running both the DTS package and Local run are equivalent(Admins).

Below is the error I get when I run this locally:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C55A1680-CD5A-11CF-8D
29-444553540000} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

But it runs fine inside the DTS package. For now, I am trying to understand why is it causing an error in the local run what needs to be done to fix.

I understand that there are newer approaches/libraries to access Registry in VB.Net but for the purposes of the program I have to find a solution using the RegObj.dll.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use COM I think My.Registry is available in many .Net Frameworks if it's not existing in the one you're using. what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The COM component is not registered on the computer. Use regsvr32 to register it.